# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when moving rows between sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, exc-bad-access, swift2

Here's what I'm trying to do:

- `UITableView` in editing mode with 2 sections.
- User can move cells from second section into first and vice versa.
- In the first section user can reorder cells as he wants.
- In the second section positioning of cells is fixed, so if user moves a cell from first section into second, it should move to a specific place, not where user want.

For implementing this behavior I have 2 arrays: one for first section and one for second section (not sure if it's the best choice).

Here's the code that controls where user should move a cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath {
    if proposedDestinationIndexPath.section == 1 {
        let item = (sourceIndexPath.section == 0 ? firstSectionItems[sourceIndexPath.row] : secondSectionItems[sourceIndexPath.row]).item
        return NSIndexPath(forRow: item.displayOrder.integerValue, inSection: 1)
    }

    return proposedDestinationIndexPath
}
```

Here's the code for moving items between sections:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let section = (source: sourceIndexPath.section, destination: destinationIndexPath.section)

    switch section {
    case (0, 0):
        let itemToMove = firstSectionItems.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
        itemToMove.item.order = destinationIndexPath.row
        firstSectionItems.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    case (1, 1):
        let itemToMove = secondSectionItems.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
        secondSectionItems.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    case (1, 0):
        let itemToMove = secondSectionItems.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
        itemToMove.item.order = destinationIndexPath.row
        firstSectionItems.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    case (0, 1):
        let itemToMove = firstSectionItems.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.row)
        itemToMove.item.order = -1
        secondSectionItems.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.row)
    default:
        break
    }

    DatabaseConnector.saveContext()
}
```

Problem is that if I have several items in the first section and I try to move last one into the second section, it crashes when I drop the cell on the second section and shows me EXC_BAD_ACCESS on App Delegate with no output to console.
Debug navigator doesn't tell me much, `moveRowAtIndexPath:` doesn't get called. The last method that gets called is `-[UISectionRowData insertRowAtIndex:inSection:rowHeight:tableViewRowData:]`.

Sometimes I get a strange message in console when it crashes:

> warning: could not load any Objective-C class information from the
>   dyld shared cache. This will significantly reduce the quality of type
>   information available.

I'm using Swift 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem was in `displayOrder` of an item in `tableView(_:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:)` method.

If you have, say, 5 elements in an array and the `displayOrder` of the one you want to insert is, say, 7, it'll crash because last `indexPath.row` in that section will be 5, but you are trying to insert with `indexPath.row = 7`, which is can't happen. You can insert with `indexPath.row = 6` though, because it's the next after the last `indexPath` in the table view.

So this is how that method now looks like:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath {
    if proposedDestinationIndexPath.section == 1 {
        let item = (sourceIndexPath.section == 0 ? firstSectionItems[sourceIndexPath.row] : secondSectionItems[sourceIndexPath.row]).item
        let rowIndex = item.displayOrder > secondSectionItems.count ? secondSectionItems.count : item.displayOrder
        return NSIndexPath(forRow: rowIndex, inSection: 1)
    }

    return proposedDestinationIndexPath
}
```

And it works just fine.

(stupid mistake :-/)